# jquery call same function on various element and events

Tags: jquery

actually i need to call same function on element1.change and element2.keyup

```
$("#element1").keyup(function(e){ 

}
```

and

```
$("#element2").change(function(e){ 

}
```

how to declare the function for two events on two elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a separate `function` and pass it instead.

```
function handler(e){
   // code;
}
$('#element1').keyup(handler);
$('#element2').change(handler);
```

If you have same event, you can easily separate the selectors by a comma or use `add()`